# What does Regex.compile do in Ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex

Specifically, my code is:

```
START_SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT =  Regexp.compile(SINGLE_LINE_COMMENTS.map { |c|
      "\s*#{Regexp.escape(c)} "
    }.join("|"))
```

What does this actually do?

Ideally, what would the JS equivalent be?

Comment: `Regex.compile` ensures that special characters are correctly escaped

Comment: So how would this look in JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regexp() [compile() method is just a synonym for Regexp.new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-c-compile). which has now been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#RegExp_Methods) too.

So this will finally [escape](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) the special characters in string passed and then finally join with "|" based on SINGLE_LINE_COMMENTS array you pass.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's just a deprecated constructor.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/884784/revisions

Comment: What about that map craziness?

Comment: @Shamoon `#{Regexp.escape(c)}` is used in map because it's possible the string has special characters.